# ¿como hacer multiplicaciones seguidas con php y colocar el resultado en diferentes input text?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

hola estoy perdido en como estructurar una secuencia de multiplicaciones si usar `if` anidados, `ifelse`,  `switch` o hasta un `array`

el problema es el siguiente, en la imagen de aquí abajo se muestra un formulario el cual tiene 3 filas para registrar proveedores cada proveedor debe tener un costo unitario diferente pero la cantidad debe ser igual es decir:
si yo en el `input` cantidad pongo un 4 y en costo unitario1 pongo otro 4 al darle click al boton del input costo total1 debe aparecer 16, luego si yo pongo en el input costo unitario2 la cantidad de 2 al darle clic al botón de costo total2 debe aparecer un 8 pero aparece un 16, pasa lo mismo en el input de abajo , cada input de costo total debe tener una cantidad diferente por que las cantidades de costo unitario varían, no se si me entiendan.
o tendría que hacer un script individual para cada proveedor ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código donde envió mis variables al php que hará las multiplicaciones:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enviartotal").click(function(){
        var costo_unitario1 = $("#costo_unitario1").val();
        var costo_unitario2 = $("#costo_unitario2").val();       
        var costo_unitario3 = $("#costo_unitario3").val();
        var cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/suma_costos_comparativapro.php",
            data: {costo_unitario1:costo_unitario1,costo_unitario2:costo_unitario2,costo_unitario3:costo_unitario3,cantidad:cantidad},
            success: function(data){              
                $('#costo_total1').val(data);
                $('#costo_total2').val(data);
                $('#costo_total3').val(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

y aquí esta mi pagina php donde estoy haciendo las operaciones de multiplicar:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die(mysqli_error());
$costo_unitario1=$_POST['costo_unitario1'];
$costo_unitario2=$_POST['costo_unitario2'];
$costo_unitario3=$_POST['costo_unitario3'];
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];


 if (is_numeric($costo_unitario1) && is_numeric($cantidad)) 
 {
    $resultado1 = $costo_unitario1 * $cantidad;
    echo $resultado1;
 }
 elseif(is_numeric($costo_unitario2)&& is_numeric($cantidad))
 {
   $resultado2 = $costo_unitario2 * $cantidad;
    echo $resultado2;
 }
elseif(is_numeric($costo_unitario3)&& is_numeric($cantidad))
 {
  $resultado3 = $costo_unitario3 * $cantidad;
  echo $resultado3;
 }
 else
 {}
?>
```

Comment: Esta mal tu if.. si el primero ya tiene valor, va a devolver ese y no va a calcular el resto. Tu echo deberia devolver todos los valores y despues guardarlos donde corresponde.

Comment: pero aun y cuando acomode mi if el retornar los valores es lo que se me dificulta ya que cada input lleva valores diferentes creo la vía mas fácil es hacerlos por individual mandar los datos de un input a una pagina php y así sucesivamente , solo quería ver si había una manera de hacerlo todo junto y evitar crear tantas paginas para muy poco codigo

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enviartotal").click(function(){
        var costo_unitario1 = $("#costo_unitario1").val();      
        var cantidad = $("#cantidad").val();       
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/suma_costos_comparativapro.php",
            data: {costo_unitario1:costo_unitario1,cantidad:cantidad},
            success: function(data){              
                $('#costo_total1').val(data);              
            }
        });
    });
});

Comment: <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die(mysqli_error());
$costo_unitario1=$_POST['costo_unitario1'];
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];

 if (is_numeric($costo_unitario1) && is_numeric($cantidad)) 
 {
  $resultado1 = $costo_unitario1 * $cantidad;
    echo $resultado1;
 } 
 else
 {}
?>

Comment: algo así , cada input individual y no mandar los datos todos juntos

Comment: Tal vez deberias mostrar **en la pregunta** usa el boton [edit] como construis la pagina. Asi podran ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummmm... Si vas a registrar estos datos en una base de datos pues está bien que uses PHP, es lo más normal del mundo, por lo que hasta ahí todo bien, pero si solo vas a procesar esa data para obtener una respuesta haciendo simples cálculos deberías en vez usar PHP para eso, usar Javascript.

Por otro lado la estructura condicional que tienes en estos momentos no sirve para aquello que necesitas, y creo que la manera más sencilla de retornar estos valores sería retornarlos como JSON después de las comprobaciones de los if:

```
$resultado = "";

if (is_numeric($costo_unitario1) && is_numeric($costo_unitario2) && is_numeric($costo_unitario3) && is_numeric($cantidad)) 
 {
    $resultado1 = $costo_unitario1 * $cantidad;
    $resultado2 = $costo_unitario2 * $cantidad;
    $resultado3 = $costo_unitario3 * $cantidad;
    $resultado = json_encode(
          array(
                     "state" => "success",
                     "resultado1" => $resultado1,
                     "resultado2" => $resultado2,
                     "resultado3" => $resultado3
           )
    );

 }else{

   $resultado = json_encode(array( "state" => "fail"));

 }

echo $resultado;
```

Y entonces en un condicional en alguna parte del codigo donde requieras usar estos valores usas el valor "state" del array para poder comprobar primero si se pueden usar esos valores , en caso tal de que si , los usas sin más, de otra manera haces lo que requieras.

Comment: Ando en el cel, por lo que no puedo formatear correcta mente la respuesta fácilmente :c